# When creating a button that goes to the next page, do I need to initialize it?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-widget

I am implementing an app using a plotter.
We are developing to move to the next page by pressing a button created using InkWell.
If you only have one button, no problem, but clicking one of the over 200 buttons will take you to the next "learning page". After that, my code is implemented so that I can do a "short learning", then come back, or move on to the next question.

Looking at other people's example code, I often see initialization or management with controllers.
Should I do that too? Below is the button code.

```
   class Syllable extends StatelessWidget{
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              centerTitle: true,
              elevation: 0.0
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: ListView(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              children: <Widget>[
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Text('',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget>[
                    LearnLevelButton(
                      text: '',
                      onTap: () async {
                          await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
                            return Home();
                          }));
                      },
                      ),
```

Below is the code with only the buttons separated.

```
    return InkWell(
          onTap: onTap,
          child: Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 20.0,
                bottom: 20.0,
                left: 22.0,
                right: 22.0,
              ),
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius),
                  border: Border.all(
                    width: 0.3,
                    color: Colors.black38,
                  ),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      blurRadius: 10.0,
                      offset: Offset(5.0, 5.0),
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
    
    


    
                ),
              ],
              gradient: gradient,
            ),
            width: width,
            height: height,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius),
                border: Border.all(
                  width: 0.3,
                  color: Colors.black26,
                ),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    blurRadius: 1.0,
                    offset: Offset(1.0, 1.5),
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
                  ),
                ],
                gradient: gradient,
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  text,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: The question isn't clear, but you don't need to initialize another screen before navigating to it.

Comment: Still not clear, you want to navigate to learningPage and comeback to the home page?

Comment: Indeed, I can't understand what you want to do either. What do you want to initialize? Why? Where?